# Premium image gallery that support WebP

Tags: magento2, image, gallery, gallery-image

Which Premium Image gallery supports WebP format for Magento 2. Or how to find does my gallery supports WebP format. And when I say support I mean no conversion. I just want to know will the extension, give me the options to work with this type of image files, put them on my product page for example, displays them on list, and just change the name, put some tags etc. Does the simple image gallery supports this format.

Magento 2.3. does not support WebP, but there are tools for that no problem.
I just want to use only this file format, and not to buy more disk space at the hosting, but I have 5000 photos +

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. But probably you need an extension like this one: https://github.com/MagestyApps/module-web-images

It allows uploading WebP images to any area of your Magento website: static pages and blocks, product gallery, product description, category description, store logo, etc.